# does boost odeint have a leapfrog algorithm?

Tags: c++, boost, differential-equations, odeint

I am using boost::odeint and so far I was using the runge_kutta4 stepper. Now I would like to switch to a leapfrog method, e.g. my iteration step should look like:

```
f(t+dt) = f(t-dt) - p * f(t)
```

So I need a multistep method, but I am a bit lost with the documentation and would like to get some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leap-frog is currently not implemented. But it should be easy to implement with the help of the Adam-Bashforth method. I have opened a ticket in our issue tracker: https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/issues/119

Comment: what are the chances this will be implemented soon ?

Comment: They are pretty high. Nearly everything already exist. We only need a small refactoring of the Adam-Bashforth method for arbitrary coefficients.

Comment: ok, I had a look at Leapfrog. It is not that easy to implement. If you need a solver for Hamiltonian or Newtonian systems you can also use one of the symplectic methods like symplectic Euler, or ymplectic_rkn_sb3a_m4_mclachlan.